# Is there some term for the English used by Yoda?

Tags: character, dialogue, star-wars

Yoda speaks in normal English with few words misplaced, mostly initial or middle words in the end. Does this kind of English have some term name associated with it?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/what-term-can-be-used-to-describe-yodas-speech) (and also [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/yodas-sentence-structure))

Comment: @Walt Checked here but not on english.SE

Comment: Of course there isn't. Yoda isn't even speaking english. That's Galactic Basic.

Comment: OK. Since this is just a copy/paste job from another stack, I'd prefer for it to remain a community wiki answer.

Comment: @Richard I guessed so, but this isn't what Community Wiki is for. More often that not we're simply linking/quoting/summarizing existing content anyway. You still answered the question with a proper answer. Community Wiki's primary intent is *not* to abstain from any reputation gain of the post (be they positive or negative) but for answers directly built by community collaboration. When quoting large parts from other third party sites and works you don't use Community Wiki either, why should this be different when that third party site is another SE site?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Because this is literally a 30-second hack-job from an accepted answer elsewhere. I made it a CW specifically to emphasise the "team effort" nature of the post, something that does fall within the acceptable uses of a CW, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Richard But it's not a "team effort" *at all*. It was written by you alone and nobody has any intent to edit it substantially. It was no team effort if it's copied from an entirely different site, that's the point.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I still don't feel right taking credit for something that required no creative or research effort on my part

Comment: @Richard Well, that's for your own morals to discuss, not for CW abuse to circumvent. You deserve that credit since you posted a proper answer. And it *did* clearly require research effort anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing heavily on the answers to a similar question on English:SE ([What term can be used to describe Yoda's speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/what-term-can-be-used-to-describe-yodas-speech));

> ""[Hyperbaton](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/H/hyperbaton.htm) and
>   [Anastrophe](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/anastrophe.htm)"
>
> 1. Hyperbaton: An inversion of normal word order. A generic term for a variety of figures involving transposition (see below), it is
>      sometimes synonymous with anastrophe.
> 2. Anastrophe: Usually synonymous and occasionally referred to as a more specific instance of hyperbaton: the changing of the position of
>      only a single word.

and

> This is more a linguistics question than an English language question
>   in my opinion.
>
> The quality of Yoda's speech that makes it sound strange to English
>   speakers - and the speakers of the majority of earth's langauges is
>   that it uses a very uncommon linguistic typology or word ordering
>   known as [Object-Subject-Verb (OSV) or sometimes Object-Agent-Verb
>   (OAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Subject_Verb).